# Unable to Access Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here][1]After Launching Jupyter Notebook, the web page from where we can use jupyter notebook is buffering it is unable to redirect to localhost 8888.
Even if I am trying to open that localhost 8888 page it's not opening.
For a long time, it buffers then shows unable to reach.

When I tried to launch Notebook:

[image: 1]

When I tried to access directly via localhost address:

[image: 2]

Comment: try to change your default browser with other like chrome or firefox and run again jupyter

Comment: Both photos are the same?! Can you update the 2nd photo?

Comment: Thanks Freddy It Worked after changing the default browser. Even now its opening in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Mario for your Edit Suggestion :)